# How to access xml in Feedjira parser classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, feedjira

Say I have the following Feedjira nested parser subclasses.  How can I access the xml for the Trunk, Branch, and Leaf classes so I can log/save it in the case of an error? Preferably just the xml for the parsed element, but I'd take the xml for the whole Trunk in the case of a Branch or Leaf.

Thanks!

```
module Feedjira
  module Parser
    class Trunk
      include SAXMachine
      include FeedEntryUtilities

      element :trunkName
      elements :branch, as: :branches, class: Branch

      def createModel
        begin
          trunk = ActiveRecordTrunk.create( name: trunkName )
          branches.each_index do |n|
            branch = branches[ n ].createModel
            branch.trunk_id = trunk.id
            branch.save!
          end
        rescue StandardError => e
          # log the error and the xml for this trunk element.  HOW??
          ::Rails.logger.error "Parse Error, xml = #{ xml }"
        end
      end
    end

    class Branch
      include SAXMachine
      include FeedEntryUtilities

      element :branchName
      elements :leaf, as: :leaves, class: Leaf

      def createModel
        begin
          trunk = ActiveRecordBranch.create( name: branchName )
          leaves.each_index do |n|
            leaf = leaves[ n ].createModel
            leaf.branch_id = branch.id
            leaf.save!
          end
        rescue StandardError => e
          # log the error and the xml for this branch element.  HOW??
          ::Rails.logger.error "Parse Error, xml = #{ xml }"
        end
      end
    end

    class Leaf
      include SAXMachine
      include FeedEntryUtilities

      element :leafName

      def createModel
        begin
          leaf = ActiveRecordLeaf.create( name: leafName )
        rescue StandardError => e
          # log the error and the xml for this leaf element.  HOW??
          ::Rails.logger.error "Parse Error, xml = #{ xml }"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```